# How to retain PL/SQL date parameter with time

Tags: plsql

I am writing  a procedure to call  built in procedure for RDS,  I need to set default values 
as 2 hours ahead for start time and end time as current system time. I am trying to use below code.
I want to execute procedure without providing variables at execution time eventually run it using dbms_scheduler so every time its run it have 2 ahead hours for start time and end time as current system time.Please let me know if below code is valid or is there a better way of doing it.

```
create or replace procedure test ( 
     v_owner IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'SYS',
     V_directory IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'TEST',
     v_start_tm IN DATE,
     v_end_tm IN DATE,
     v_parallel IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1,
     v_output IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'True')
IS
     start_tm DATE := sysdate - (120/1440);
     end_tm DATE := SYSDATE;
     v_sql varchar2(500);

begin 
    v_sql :='BEGIN  
    rdsadmin.rdsadmin_rman_util.backup_archivelog_date(v_owner,v_directory, 
    start_tm,end_tm,v_parallel,v_output);END;';
   execute immediate v_sql;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code is really not making sense.  execute immediate will not work like that.  I would recommend getting a PL/SQL book.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is directly answered in the Oracle documentation.

> Example 7-1 Invoking Subprogram from Dynamic PL/SQL Block
>
> In this example, the dynamic PL/SQL block is an anonymous PL/SQL block that invokes a subprogram created at schema level.

Here is the link: [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#GUID-30ADFC05-8DFB-4C8A-831D-426C2E97F217__CHDIEFCJ)

Pay attention to how they invoke the `USING` clause.

Comment: Thanks Del for the link in was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to backup archived redo logs generated in last 2 hours for an Amazon RDS Oracle DB instance then scheduling the above stored procedure with minor tweaks should be good enough, however there is a minor catch(Point 2 below).

1.Firstly the stored procedure has to be changed as below,

```
create or replace procedure test ( 
       v_owner IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'SYS',
       V_directory IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'TEST',
       v_parallel IN NUMBER DEFAULT 1)
   IS
       start_tm DATE := sysdate - (120/1440);
       end_tm DATE   := SYSDATE;

    begin 

    rdsadmin.rdsadmin_rman_util.backup_archivelog_date(
        p_owner               => v_owner, 
        p_directory_name      => V_directory,
        p_from_date           => start_tm,
        p_to_date             => end_tm,
        p_parallel            => v_parallel,  
        p_rman_to_dbms_output => TRUE);

    end;
```

2. If you intend to schedule this every 2 hours using DBMS_SCHEDULER, you must be vary about JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES parameter(Please read : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/initparams108.htm). If the number of jobs at a given instance is more that this parameter then the job will be queued up and there could be a delay to start the job which in turn would delay the start time.You could miss archiving those files. 
   Hence my recommendation is to trigger the stored procedure using batch script from operating system.For Linux/unix systems cronjob can be used ,for windows Task scheduler is a decent scheduler.

Comment: Thanks @VN'sCorner for input about schedulling jobs with dbms_scheduler.While calling the procedure when i declare the variable as start_tm DATE := 'sysdate  (120/1440)'  it gives me ORA-01858 error  , could you help me with the solution for this ?

Comment: It should be start_tm DATE := sysdate - (120/1440); Please refer dbfiddle link with the query for complete solution https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83408dde5b3ee7ec2281000160cd6491

Comment: Thanks heaps @VN'sCorner for your help i tried it with start_tm DATE := sysdate - (120/1440);  gives me the output as required fine